# How to capture multi-line output of a helper function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I have written a small Javascript script for AdWords, which loops through several campaigns and adgroups of multiple accounts and then saves the results.

While the script works perfectly fine, I want to store the complete results once the looping is finished and send it off as an email, and I have a hard time making it work.

The code looks like this:

```
function main() {
MccApp.accounts().withIds([arr1,arr2,...,arrX])..executeInParallel('abc', 'afterProcessAllClientAccounts');
}

function abc() {
// Select campaigns, adgroups and loop through them...
// Now comes the somewhat critical part:

var n = 0;

while(aditer.hasNext()) {
  n++;
  aditer.next();
}

if(n < 4){

Logger.log('Campaign: ' + ag.getCampaign() + ' | AdGroup: ' + ag.getName() + ' | Ads: ' + n);

}
}

function afterProcessAllClientAccounts(results) {
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
var result = results[i].getReturnValue();
Logger.log(result);
}
}
```

Now I would like to send an email with the multi-line `Logger.log()` output once the looping is done and I run into problems. AdWords Apps Script has a prebuilt mailing method:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
```

If I put it into the helper function, I get an email every time a loop is finished for one of the array elements, at the same time I did not find a valid way to put it in the main function as the outputing happens in the helper function.

Hence how can I aggregate the output and store it in a variable that is callable from within the main function?

**EDIT:** I have added the `afterProcessAllClientAccounts` function to the code. Calling it like this, the final `Logger.log()` output simply gives me the last specified result of each `adGroup` loop of the `account`. Hence for `n` rows of `arr[n]`, I get either a proper output or simply `undefined`. The problem is that the while `adGroup` loop seems to reset the logger completely. Another solution I tried today was pushing each log result in the `if (n < 4)` statement to an array as such:

```
var test = [];

function main() {
//foo
}

function abc(){
//foo
// while adGroup loop:

var n = 0;

while(aditer.hasNext()) {
  n++;
  aditer.next();
}

if(n < 4){

var c = 'Campaign: ' + ag.getCampaign() + ' | AdGroup: ' + ag.getName() + ' | Ads: ' + n;

test.push(c);
//or
test[test.length] = 'Campaign: ' + ag.getCampaign() + ' | AdGroup: ' + ag.getName() + ' | Ads: ' + n;
}

//back in the adGroup loop
Logger.log(test);
}
//end of function
}
```

Also in this case, the log only contained either an `[]` or the actual correct output per row if the condition was fulfilled, but it never truly appended the values to `test`, it rather replaced them, with the very final output being simply an empty array. It may be a very small detail I'm overlooking here and I sat on this with several other more experienced people, none of which found a solution.

**EDIT 2:** Adapted the code with concatenating all single results into an array. Output returns the correct number of rows (equal to the number of accounts), but the array is always empty.

```
function afterProcessAllClientAccounts(results) {
for (var i = 0; i <= results.length; i++) {
var result = [];
var s_result = results[i].getReturnValue();
result.concat(s_result);
Logger.log(result);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/features/mcc#working_on_accounts_in_parallel), you can use the function `executeInParallel(functionName, optionalCallbackFunctionName);` where the parameter "functionName" is the function that will be excecuted for all the accounts, in your case the function is called 'abc'.

The other parameter "optionalCallbackFunctionName" is the name of the function that will be executed after all the accounts have been processed.

So you can return the same string you used in the Log `'Campaign: ' + ag.getCampaign() + ' | AdGroup: ' + ag.getName() + ' | Ads: ' + n`

Then the callback function will receive this information as an array and then you can concatenate all the strings into one big string so you now can send just one email with the information of all the different accounts. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Gerardo, thank you for answering. I read in the documentation about the optionalCallbackFunction, but I could not put it to work for me. While I logically get the notion of it and also what you wrote in your last paragraph, I can not make it work for me with code, unfortunately. I hate to ask this, but could you explicitly give an example of how you would code your last paragraph? Instead of Logger, I tried other code such as `var c = [ag.getCampaign(), ag.getName(), n];` and then `results.push(c);` with `results` being a global variable array and using it as the `body` param. Didn't work.

Comment: I have tried your approach thoroughly over the day and it does not work for me at all unfortunately. I get only a split of the logged results if i would logg it in the `if (n < 4) {}` statement and most of the callback function's return value's are `undefined`.

Comment: could you edit your post with your updated code? Does the callback function is not being executed? or doesn't it receive the result from the 'abc' function?

Comment: Edited the code with the callback function in the main (1st) codeblock and describing another solution I tried today in the second block. In both cases the code is executed, also results are received, the problem is, that single adGroup values are not saved, only the final values of each loop per account. Thank you for taking the time for this, Gerardo.

Comment: Have you tried concatenating all the result of the function "afterProcessAllClientAccounts" in one variable and then call Logger.log with that variable?

Comment: Hey, yes. Please see the updated answer with code above. While it returns the correct number of rows, the array (or also a string concatenation as in "Results: ") is always empty.